# How to Aggregate timestamp Values to 15 MIns?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some values for some particular timestam like

```
  Time                          Value
  18/10/2016 00:00:00           10
  18/10/2016 00:05:00           20
  18/10/2016 00:10:00           30
  18/10/2016 00:15:00           40
  18/10/2016 00:20:00           50
  18/10/2016 00:25:00           60
  18/10/2016 00:30:00           70
```

I want to aggregate it to 15 Mins data. My aggregation should be like at 18/10/2016 00:15:00 it should take the average of 5mins,10Mins and 15Mins to give 15th Min data.

My output should be like

```
  Time                          value
  18/10/2016 00:15:00           30
  18/10/2016 00:30:00           60
```

Is there any way to get this in oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
select (trunc(time, 'HOUR') + 15 * trunc(extract(minute from time) / 15) / (60 * 24)) as time,
       sum(value)
from t
group by (trunc(time, 'HOUR') + 15 * trunc(extract(minute from time) / 15) / (60 * 24));
```

Comment: My time range is dynamic. I can give any start date and end date. I am getting data in my database as 5 minutes. With these 5 mins data i want to aggregate like i mentioned. Need help on this.